# Are all items in TFS technically the same?

Tags: tfs

In a pure technical sense: It looks to me that the "Backlog" is in fact treated like any other "iteration". Is that true?

Overall, it seems to me that entries in the "Team Foundation Server" are in fact a list of items which can be structured by linking them together.

And fields like Work Item Type, Iteration, Status, etc. are in fact "attributes" for each item.

Is that true? Or are different items in fact stored in different tables or data structures?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question...  Things such as Work Item type, status, etc are all fields in a Work Item.  A work item can belong to an iteration, but they are different types of objects.  Are you trying to pull data directly from the TFS database instead of using the API?

Answer (score 1):

All of the Work Items (Bugs, PBI, Story, Test Case, Feedback *, Code Review *, etc) are all stored in the one set of tables. You can use witadmin.exe to export a work item type (e.g. "bug") and edit the fields available, or add new fields.

In fact some part of Test Plan, and Test Suit is also a work item. And you can add your own types.

However, many things in TFS are not work items and are stored outside the Work Item Store. E.g. Builds, Releases, Test Runs, and Test Results.

The data is all accessible through the client API and the Rest API. You should never access the database directly...

Comment: For the record: Test Plans and Suites became work items with 2013 update 4.